# What are the RAM-only microcontrollers intended for?

Tags: microcontroller

While looking for some detailing on part number construction for Texas Instruments's MSP430 series, I came across this wiki page: [TI MSP430](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430)

There is a statement,

> "L" as in the MSP430L09x series, which indicates a RAM-only part; it must remain continuously powered to retain its programming

While I haven't able to validate the above after going through the [datasheet on the official website](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430L092), the question that bumps me is, if at all there is one such part, what could be the appropriate application to use it?

Comment: Maybe a peripheral where the program is always uploaded from the host at power on?

Comment: Indeed a valid point, but what real-life application do we see that does it this way?

Comment: All FPGAs do this. It probably also has the benefit that RAM is faster to read from and write to than Flash. But beyond that I can only speculate.

Comment: I used the ADSP-21xx parts, which were RAM-only. They included a boot process on power-up where they could fill that memory from an external EEPROM, for example. I haven't looked at the part you are discussing, though. So I can't tell you about its case. But that's the kind of thing I'd look for.

Comment: Some types of secure applications may want to "burn after reading" - think locks or bank security tokens.

Comment: The freescale DSPs I used were RAM only and had a bootloader similar to what @jonk describes, but got  their program code via SPI.

Comment: Yes, the datasheet links to a loader: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau324/slau324.pdf and references this as being for "development".

Comment: An example of the "secure application": old arcade machines had self-destructing code tied to a backup battery to impair copying of the software. https://hackaday.com/2016/09/15/desuiciding-capcom-arcade-boards/

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't have an insight on how it could be used. I'll read further!

Comment: This could be a related case.  I've seen PCI card designs which had an FPGA which didn't store its own firmware.  There was no Flash memory on the PCI card.  The host CPU downloaded the firmware into the FPGA from the hard drive.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - I'm pretty sure FPGAs are RAM-based because the lithography process used to make them either can't make flash, or can't make flash inexpensively.

Comment: @ConnorWolf CPLDs are flash based. Albeit they have fewer gates.

Comment: @NickAlexeev That's a reasonable design for a PCI card that always has a host, though. (At least until Linux kernel developers run into your legal team)

Comment: @BrianDrummond: or "burn after tampering". Quite a few anti tempering mechanisms are based on that.

Comment: @immibis sounds like you have a particular story in mind there.  Anything you can share?  IIRC, nvidia graphics cards work that way too.

Comment: @Baldrickk Just about all moderately complex hardware actually. Network controllers and graphics cards seem to be particularly bad, but have a look at all the stuff included in [linux-firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/). Those are all firmware "blobs" (files) needed by Linux drivers... some were contributed voluntarily by the hardware companies, some probably had to be cajoled out of them, and quite possibly some are there illegally (but the company is out of business or just isn't bothered to sue).

Comment: @immibis I hadn't realised that it was so common.  I thought that the usual process for firmware on PCI cards was to store it, and a new 'blob' would only be transfered for a firmware update. At least, when I last checked (which would be a while ago) AMD(ATI?) cards had installed firmware, while nvidia cards had a bootloader and not much else, relying on a blob being uploaded each boot.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The point of the "L" series is to support very low supply voltages (0.9 V; what you'd get from a single battery cell); the [web page](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430l092) says:

> Typical applications for this device include single-cell systems requiring a full analog signal chain.

The missing flash is *not* a goal; it's an unfortunate side effect of the voltage range. Chapter 8 of the User's Guide says:

> This chapter describes how the MSP430L092 loader code is used to build an autonomous microcontroller solution. The loader approach is chosen as nonvolatile memory is not available for native ultra-low supply voltages.

You are supposed to ask TI to create a chip with your code in ROM (this is what the "C" series is for). However, during development (when you do not yet know what goes into the ROM), or when you do not have many devices (so the fixed ROM overhead would be too expensive), you have to use an "L" chip without ROM:

[image: MSP430x09x debugging scenarios]

Comment: "Not a deliberate feature"  isn't accurate.  It certainly wasn't an accident.  Do you mean "desirable"?

Comment: Yes, the intent is more important.

Answer (score 14):

Many PC-connected devices are build without a ROM, since they can be easily programmed by the host. For instance, all WiFi modules I have seen are programmed by their driver when the said driver is loaded. This saves money on expensive flash-ROM (storage on the PC is much cheaper) and makes firmware updates seamless for the end user.

This concept is not unique to WiFi, but it turned out to be very useful in this case in particular, because many WiFi chipsets are released while the corresponding specification is still in the draft stage, so frequent firmware upgrades are to be expected.

Comment: Also any embedded processor that works alongside other processors. Typically the master processor starts up all the other processors and sends them their code.